# Anylogic Error "Not unique database" using date from an excel table and trying to seperate it based on a condition to 2 queues

Tags: anylogic

I am writing my masterthesis and have to built a simple model but struggeling a little.
I use the following data (order information) from an excel table.
(Screenshot Table) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTUZJ.png)
I started my model with a source that creates orders as agents. Now I want to split them into two queues based on the criteria if it is a "Sonderbau" or "Serienbau".
(Screenshot 2)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHNFl.png)

But I always get an error, running the model. It always tells me "Not unique database".

I already tried to insert a query at the source like described in previous posts but it is still not working.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, I am very new to AnyLogic and you should take my advice with a pinch of salt.

You could make the Condition in your `selectOutput` a dynamic value instead of Database reference if you want to route agents based your agent variable "abteilung".

If you click on the dynamic value field, a little lightbulb displays a tip: "use self; agent". You have to define a variable "abteilung" for the agent passing trough your select output that gets its value from the corresponding column in your database.

To refer to this variable in your select output you can use: agent.abteilung. To futher route this agent you could use Condition: `agent.abteilung.equals("Serienbau")`. This is assuming that the agents are inserted to your flowchart from your agent population. If you don't bring agents from your already created population this won't work.

In a similar case I used these Source settings for an agent Type  called "Products" created from a database table.

Projects -> Simulation: Main -> Start Date: "Specify here a start date for simulation".

1. Source -> Arrivals defined by: Arrival table in database
2. Database table: "your database table"
3. Arrival date: "column where your date is"
4. Multiple agents per arrival: yes
5. Agents per arrival: "column where the amount is"

Agent -> New agent: "Product" and check parameters.

PS I noticed that you don't have any delays so the products will just be created and destroyed. I felt obligated to chime in, since I was having a similar problem as a beginner working on my thesis. :)

Comment: Don't forget to check out: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/agent-db.html#creating-a-new-agent-population-based-on-db-data.

Comment: Hello Elmo, 
thank you so much for your response. I just saw it right now ;) and to be honest I am so tired from all the desperation that I have to take a break now. I will check on it on Sunday/Monday and let you know if it worked. The delays I jsut left out here to simplefy the model ;) I guess there will be some other problems coming up then. haha

Comment: Hope you were able to solve your problem! I edited my answer on the Source properties since this is a more simple way to add the agents to the flowchart for this purpose.

Comment: to be honest, I used a workaround for that. But thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL query is finding more than 1 entry. You essentially tell it to find all entries with "Serienbau", of which there are many.

However, I think you want to achieve something entirely different, namely to make your agents move through different `SelectOutput` exits based on *their* characteristic, right?

You need to revisit the basics of how to create agents from data and then access agent characteristics. Best way forward: do *ALL* AnyLogic step-by-step tutorials first, tbh :)